# jhipster control center with oauth2 keycloak docker

Tags: dockerfile, jhipster

I have generated jhipster application using sample
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/test-integration/jdl-samples/ms-mf-vue-consul-oauth2-mysql-memcached/blog-store.jdl

I have started keycloak ,

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up
```

and added `127.0.0.1 keycloak` to hosts, then when trying to run

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-control-center.yml up
```

failed with

```
Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster"
```

how to resolve "http://keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster" in jhipster control center docker

Comment: Does `ping keycloak` work as expected?

Comment: Yeah ping working , in host machine, i can login successfully via browser.

Comment: but jhipster control center not working

Comment: I'm sorry. I've never used the Control Center app so I'm not able to help.

Comment: is it been solved? I have the same issue

Comment: No i have dropped using jhipster-control-center